# Yarn workspace - use `"type": "module"` for entire workspace?

Tags: node.js, es6-modules, yarn-workspaces

Can't find any exact info on this.

I have set `"type": "module"` in my workspace root `package.json`, and I kind of assumed it would work across all workspaces, but it doesn't, and i still have to add the `type` to all `package.json`'s.

Is this possible? And if so, how do I get it working?

Added Note: I'm on my mobile, so no code access to copy, but, the specific error I'm getting is:

`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each workspace is considered as an individual project and has it's own dependencies and configurations.
Yarn, or any package manager that supports monorepos/workspaces as far as I know, does not support applying or extending the outer package JSON to the individual workspaces.

This is by design as each individual workspace/project may have different dependencies and require different configurations.